# Number of columns does not correspond to the number of rows in the header in row(s) Magento 2

Tags: import, magento2

I am trying to upload products in **Magento 2.2.6** from default import using CSV. I am getting this error while checking data on CSV.
[image]

I have double check my CSV file has accurate columns and values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help someone I found the solution with the help of this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263660/38088).
In my data, there were **", "** that was causing this issue after removing coma from the values the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the number on your column or rows, Delete those numbers and make sure no empty space before you import!